# Inserting data in Mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a drop down list as well a input type for for category and name but in both the case as i click next it directs me to another page but nothing saves in my database. 
company_account is the table name in which data has to be inserted it has four rows id, category, cname, about

```
<?php include( "./inc/header.inc.php");
 require( "./inc/connect.inc.php"); ?>

<div>
<form action = "payment.php" method= "POST">
<select id="category" name="category" class="old_ui_selector">
    <option value="0" selected="1">Choose your category</option>
    <option value="">Accounting Firm</option>
    <option value="">Agriculture</option>
    <option value="">Automotive</option>
    <option value="">Aerospace/Defence</option>
    <option value="">Building Material</option>

</select>
</div>
<br>
<input type = "text" name="cname" placeholder= "Name"/>
<br><br>
By clicking Next you agree to the <a href="terms.php" style="color: #008781">Terms and Conditions.</a>
<br>
<input type = "submit" name="comp" value="Next"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['comp']))
{
    $category=$_GET['category'];
    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
    $ins=mysql_query("insert into company_account (category) values ('$category')");
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO company_account VALUES ('','$category','$cname','$about')");
    if($ins)
        if($insert)
    {
        echo "<br>".$category."inserted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: file name is payment.php ?

Comment: yes this is the file which openes as one clicks on Next

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it directs me to another page"?

Comment: its submit on payment.ph if you want to submit on same page then  do action=""

Comment: payment.php opens

Comment: i hav changed action=""

Comment: it saves the cname to database what about category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** `mysql`: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the **MySQLi** or **PDO_MySQL** extension should be used.

You have provided with the `form action` and that will redirect after clicking the submit button.

You have written the `INSERT STATEMENT` in the same page itself and that will not even work for you.

> First Remove up the `action=""` and then you redirect it based on the data saved.

**HTML:**

```
<form action = "" method= "POST">
</form>
```

And you Option value is missing out values and after the form is submitted the values will not be entered into the DB. Hence you need to do the following.

**Replace:**

```
<option value="">Accounting Firm</option>
```

With:

```
<option value="Accounting Firm">Accounting Firm</option>
```

**PHP Code for Insert:**

You Insert Code will not work since you have not provided with the table values for insert operations.

**Syntax:**

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(`columnname1`,`columnname2`,.....) VALUES(VALUE1,VALUE1,....)
```

Hence you are advised to use the correct table structure for the Operations and then insert the data.

**INSERT QUERY:**

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO company_account(`category`,`name`,`about`) VALUES ('$category','$cname','$about')");
```

You can `insert all in the single query` itself and then redirect using the header location.

Use `header Location` for redirection to particular page after the data has been saved.

```
header('location : http://www.google.co.in');
```

**PHP PART:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['comp']))
{
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO company_account(`category`,`name`,`about`) VALUES ('$category','$cname','$about')");
    $rows = mysql_affected_rows();
    if($rows=0)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
        ob_start(); // Refresh the Output Buffer
        header('location: http://www.google.co.in');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

> **Note:** `$about` you are using in the Insert Statement but no values are provided over to the Insert Statement. Please check to that.

Comment: i have changed action="" it saves cname to database what about category?
 also it creates two rows in table instead of one!

Comment: where to use header location

Comment: @sanchit. Check my insert query over to the answer

Comment: only cname gets inserted to database not the category. help me in solving that too

Comment: Now check the PHP part which i have given. Ensure that all the values are passed over to the query

Comment: to be on safer side i have deleted about row from table still same thing happens cname goes in database not the category

Comment: You have an Error over here: Replace `<option value="">Accounting Firm</option>` with `<option value="Accounting Firm">Accounting Firm</option>`. Since you are running out of option value here.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\company_account.php on line 111

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\company_account.php:103) in C:\xampp\htdocs\company_account.php on line 118

Comment: For `Cannot modify header information` use the `ob_start()` for redirection purpose. Use `ob_start()` above the `header()`

Comment: what to fill inside option value

Comment: oh great it goes to database.

Comment: Change this `$rows = $insert->num_rows;` to `$rows =mysql_num_rows();`

Comment: See the PHP Part Now. Sorry its my mistake the above comment. Let me know if you still face error

Comment: two errors:
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\company_account.php on line 109

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\company_account.php:103) in C:\xampp\htdocs\company_account.php on line 117

Comment: You are inserting `$about` right and where do you get that value.. Tell me

Comment: Another thing you do a check: echo "INSERT INTO company_account(`category`,`name`,`about`) VALUES ('$category','$cname','$about')"; exit; Try this line before the mysql_query(); ans stop the execution and put the echoed statement into the DB snd check for Error

Comment: i have removed about both from database and code my code looks like

<?php
if(isset($_POST['comp']))
{
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO company_account(`category`,`cname`) VALUES ('$category','$cname')");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows();
    if($rows=0)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
        ob_start();
        header('payment.php');
    }
}
?>

Comment: Try this i have made some changes to the code: <?php 
if(isset($_POST['comp'])) 
 { 
  $category=$_POST['category']; 
  $cname = $_POST['cname']; 
  $query="INSERT INTO company_account(`category`,`cname`) VALUES ('".$category."','".$cname."')";
   mysql_query($query); 
  $rows = mysql_affected_rows(); 
  if($rows=0) 
   { 
    echo mysql_error(); 
   } 
   else 
    { 
     ob_start(); 
     header('payment.php'); 
    } 
   } 
?>

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\company_account.php:103) in C:\xampp\htdocs\company_account.php on line 117


still occurs

Comment: Where you are having `payment.php` page. Inside the current folder itself or some other folder. If you have in the same folder try giving `header(location:payment.php);exit;` Orelse navigate to the folder in the header location like `header(location:../index.php);exit;`

Comment: You must use exit; after the header is relocated

Comment: Try using this in the else part:  ob_start(); 
     header('location: payment.php');
     exit;

Comment: If that too fails try to change the header location as `header('Location: payment.php');` The letter `L` as Capital in header

Comment: I hope so all the error will be rectified and you will be  getting the proper output as required.

Comment: Share me if you still face any hindrance.

Comment: My final code: (error still occurs and payment.php doesnot opens)

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['comp']))
    {
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
    $query="INSERT INTO company_account(category,cname) VALUES ('".$category."','".$cname."')";
    $insert = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_affected_rows();
    if($rows=0) { echo mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
    ob_start();
    header('Location: payment.php');
    exit;
    }
    }
 ?>

Comment: My final code: (error still occurs and page doesnot redirects to payment.php)

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['comp']))
    {
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
    $query="INSERT INTO company_account(category,cname) VALUES ('".$category."','".$cname."')";
    $insert = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_affected_rows();
    if($rows=0) { echo mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
    ob_start();
    header('Location: payment.php');
    exit;
    }
    }
 ?>

Comment: both payment.php and company_account.php are in same folder

Comment: Try using script for redirection: `window.location.href = 'somepage.html';` where you have used `header()` and for this you don't need `ob_start()` and `exit'` when using `window.location.href`

Comment: Code will be like this: <?php 
if(isset($_POST['comp'])) 
 { 
  $category=$_POST['category']; 
  $cname = $_POST['cname']; 
  $query="INSERT INTO company_account(`category`,`cname`) VALUES ('".$category."','".$cname."')";
  mysql_query($query); 
  $rows = mysql_affected_rows(); 
  if($rows=0) 
   { 
    echo mysql_error(); 
   } 
   else 
    { 
     ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href = 'payment.php';
     </script>
     <?php
    } 
   } 
?>

Comment: Happy to hear from you. Thanks.. You shall award my answer as correct one and upvote it  if the solution solves your Error. Awaiting for your positive response from you:)

Comment: Had a very tough and hard luck times but finally succeed in the End. Happy that you got the output. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You have a few issues there, the first is you are using mysql, either update it to mysqli or better still PDO.

Second your form is submitting using POST and yet you try to collect the category using GET.

You also need to supply the contents of your connect.inc.php WITHOUT THE IP AND PASSWORD so people can have a look at the config.

I would suggest before going any further you have read here and get a better understanding before you proceed.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Best of luck.

Comment: +1 Also I would recommend looking at Alex's youtube channel, codecourse for a solid grasp of php fundamentals and good practice.